# Nested analysis for categorical variables in SPSS

Tags: categorical-data, spss, log-linear

I have categorical data in the form of correct response (0/1 for each item respectively) and prevalence of a misconception (0/1 for each misconception on each item) from a pre and post assessment.

Ideally, I could use the pre/post as the independent variable in a chi-square analysis for each item/misconception. However, I have noticed that teacher/school appears to have a significant effect on student performance (both on an item-by-item and overall basis), and there's an uneven amount of students from each school in the sample.

I think a loglinear analysis would be appropriate here (though I could be wrong and welcome correction), but I am unsure as to how to properly stage this in SPSS and am wondering whether it's possible to nest the effect of teacher/school within that of curriculum exposure (pre/post) or whether that is even necessary.

More about the sample: n=308 (for both pre and post, total data points = 616). Students were assessed with essentially identical pre/post tests before and after completing a pilot curriculum.

Comment: Do you have one measure per person? How does teacher/school come in? Can you describe the structure of your data?

Comment: There is one measure (coded as a 1 or a 0) per person per item, and per each misconception on that item (item correctness and misconception prevalence are separate). Teacher/school (coded nominally) had a significant effect on student performance when I ran quantitative analyses, and chi-square reveals a similar trend. I've actually decided to split the seven teachers/schools into two groups, however, based on similarities in the socioeconomic status of their students (via prevalence of Free and Reduced Lunch).

Comment: I think I would run a logistic regression, and include teacher/school as a dummy variable.